# MVC Model Validation From Database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a very simple Model, that needs to get validated from Database

```
public class UserAddress
{
    public string CityCode {get;set;}
}
```

`CityCode` can have values that are only available in my database table.

I know i can do something like.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Address(UserAddress model)
{
    var connection = ; // create connection
    var cityRepository = new CityRepository(connection);

    if (!cityRepository.IsValidCityCode(model.CityCode))
    {
        // Added Model error
    }
}
```

This seems very `WET` as I have to use this model at lot of placed and adding the same logic each place seems like i am not using MVC Architecture properly.

*So, what is the best pattern to validate model from Database ?*

**NOTE:**
Most of the validation are single field lookup from Database, other validation may include combination of field. But right now I am happy with single field lookup validation, as long as it is `DRY` and is not using too much reflection it is acceptable.

**NO CLIENT SIDE VALIDATION :** 
*To anyone who is answering in terms of client side validation, I do not need any such validation, most of my validation are server sided, and I need the same, please do not answer with Client Side Validation methods.*

---

P.S. If any one can give me hint how to do a attribute based validation from Database, will be extremely greatful.

Comment: Do you have some other examples of database validation you want to perform? Are there many lookups you need to compare against? Trying to draw some commonality to see how generic we can be.

Comment: @mattytommo - most of them are lookup! majority are single field lookup, which other validation may include combination of field. But right now i am happy with single field lookup validation, as long as it is dry and not using too much reflection it is acceptable.

Comment: This is a common problem with lookups unfortunately, there's debate as to whether they should sit in the database, or whether they should sit in the application as enums or something similar. Based on your setup, you could create a generic validation attribute `[ValidLookupValue]` which takes in a `type(T)` and validates that the value is in the seleced lookup (you may have to have your lookups implement an interface or base class to achieve this though).

Comment: @mattytommo - I think this is the way to go, but i might run into few complexity, the MVC Project knows nothing about how connection are created n things like that, So the question arises, where should be Validation Attribute be placed, in MVC Project or Database Layer ?

Comment: @mattytommo - if i am placing the `[ValidLookupValue]` in MVC Project, how do I provide the repository to it ?

Comment: @mattytommo - if the database table is huge, i don't think one will say to use `enum`.

Comment: You should have your attribute in your MVC project, but it would communicate to your business logic layer (or something similar if you have one), which in turn would call the database. As for enums, it depends how you structure it some people have a table per lookup type, so in that case it could be converted to an enum per lookup type.

Comment: this doesn't answer your question but perhaps another point of view will give you an alternative approach. imho MVC architecture should be ignorant of a database, which is just an implementation for data storage. data storage calls should be done in an API layer that is referenced by your MVC project (as service layer). that whole separation of concerns thing that is often hard to keep intact.

Comment: This is more of a SoC issue. To make this Dry, you want your DB calls wrapped and layered.

Comment: SoC ? Separation of Concern ?

Comment: Yes. I understand why you want to use Data Annotations. But the mechanism should be a call to a validation service or layer that makes a call like `Bool DataManager.ValidateCity(City)`

Comment: Instead of such validation, why don't you set foreign key with enforcing validation of foreign key.

Comment: @AkashKava - return proper error message to user ?

Comment: @PaRiMaLRaJ, are you looking for generic solution, in which you have to pass the only property name and it will get validated?

Answer (score 38):

---

Please check the **EDIT** from attached from the middle of this answer, for more elaborate and generic solution.

---

Following is my solution to do a simple Attribute based Validation. Create an attribute -

```
public class Unique : ValidationAttribute
{
    public Type ObjectType { get; private set; }
    public Unique(Type type)
    {
        ObjectType = type;
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (ObjectType == typeof(Email))
        {
            // Here goes the code for creating DbContext, For testing I created List<string>
            // DbContext db = new DbContext();
            var emails = new List<string>();
            emails.Add("ra@ra.com");
            emails.Add("ve@ve.com");

            var email = emails.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Contains(((Email)value).EmailId));

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            else
                return new ValidationResult("Mail already exists");
        }

        return new ValidationResult("Generic Validation Fail");
    }
}
```

I created a simple model to test -

```
public class Person
{
    [Required]
    [Unique(typeof(Email))]
    public Email PersonEmail { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public GenderType Gender { get; set; }
}

public class Email
{
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
}
```

Then I created following View -

```
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.Person
@using WebApplication1.Controllers;

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreatePersonPost", "Sale"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PersonEmail)

    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, GenderType.Male) @GenderType.Male.ToString()
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, GenderType.Female) @GenderType.Female.ToString()
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Gender)

    <input type="submit" value="click" />
}
```

Now When I enter the same Email - `ra@ra.com` and click on Submit button I can get errors in my `POST` action, as shown below.

[image]

---

**EDIT** Here goes more generic and detailed answer.

---

Create `IValidatorCommand` -

```
public interface IValidatorCommand
{
    object Input { get; set; }
    CustomValidationResult Execute();
}

public class CustomValidationResult
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Lets assume we have our `Repository` and `UnitOfWork` defined in following way -

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    List<TEntity> GetAll();
    TEntity FindById(object id);
    TEntity FindByName(object name);
}

public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Dispose();
    void Save();
    IRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
}
```

Now lets created our own `Validator Commands` -

```
public interface IUniqueEmailCommand : IValidatorCommand { }

public interface IEmailFormatCommand : IValidatorCommand { }

public class UniqueEmail : IUniqueEmailCommand
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public UniqueEmail(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
    public object Input { get; set; }

    public CustomValidationResult Execute()
    {
        // Access Repository from Unit Of work here and perform your validation based on Input
        return new CustomValidationResult { IsValid = false, ErrorMessage = "Email not unique" };
    }
}

public class EmailFormat : IEmailFormatCommand
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public EmailFormat(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
    public object Input { get; set; }

    public CustomValidationResult Execute()
    {
        // Access Repository from Unit Of work here and perform your validation based on Input
        return new CustomValidationResult { IsValid = false, ErrorMessage = "Email format not matched" };
    }
}
```

Create our `Validator Factory` which will give us a particular command based on Type.

```
public interface IValidatorFactory
{
    Dictionary<Type,IValidatorCommand> Commands { get; }
}

public class ValidatorFactory : IValidatorFactory
{
    private static Dictionary<Type,IValidatorCommand> _commands = new Dictionary<Type, IValidatorCommand>();

    public ValidatorFactory() { }        

    public Dictionary<Type, IValidatorCommand> Commands
    {
        get
        {
            return _commands;
        }
    }

    private static void LoadCommand()
    {
        // Here we need to use little Dependency Injection principles and
        // populate our implementations from a XML File dynamically
        // at runtime. For demo, I am passing null in place of UnitOfWork
        _commands.Add(typeof(IUniqueEmailCommand), new UniqueEmail(null));
        _commands.Add(typeof(IEmailFormatCommand), new EmailFormat(null));
    }

    public static IValidatorCommand GetCommand(Type validatetype)
    {
        if (_commands.Count == 0)
            LoadCommand();            

        var command = _commands.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == validatetype);
        return command.Value ?? null;
    }
}
```

And the renovated Validation Attribute -

```
public class MyValidateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public Type ValidateType { get; private set; }
    private IValidatorCommand _command;
    public MyValidateAttribute(Type type)
    {
        ValidateType = type;            
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        _command = ValidatorFactory.GetCommand(ValidateType);
        _command.Input = value;
        var result = _command.Execute();

        if (result.IsValid)
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        else
            return new ValidationResult(result.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Finally we can use our attribute as follows -

```
public class Person
{
    [Required]
    [MyValidate(typeof(IUniqueEmailCommand))]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public GenderType Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Output as follows -

[image]

---

**EDIT** Detailed explanation to make this solution more generic.

---

Lets say I have a property `Email` where I need to do following validations -

1. Format
2. Length
3. Unique

In that case we can create `IEmailCommand` inherited from `IValidatorCommand`. Then inherit `IEmailFormatCommand`, `IEmailLengthCommand` and `IEmailUniqueCommand` from `IEmailCommand`.

Our `ValidatorFactory` will hold the pool of all three command implementations in `Dictionary<Type, IValidatorCommand> Commands`.

Now instead of decorating our `Email` property with three commands, we can decorate it with `IEmailCommand`.

In this case, our `ValidatorFactory.GetCommand()` method needs to be changed. Instead of returning one command every time, it should return all matching commands for a particular type. So basically its signature should be `List<IValidatorCommand> GetCommand(Type validatetype)`.

Now as we can get all the commands associated with a property we can loop the commands and get the Validation results in our `ValidatorAttribute`.

Comment: seems good enough. But how do provide `CityRepository` to `UniqueValidationAttribute` ?

Comment: Create `RepositoryType` property in `UniqueValidationAttribute` and set it in the same way like setting the `ObjectType`.

Comment: @PaRiMaLRaJ Why doesn't this answer suit you?

Comment: @OmriAharon - this is the most close to acceptable answer, still looking for better ones though !

Comment: @PaRiMaLRaJ, please check the updated answer with more generic solution.

Comment: this seems very nice!

Comment: @PaRiMaLRaJ I updated my answer with more detailed explanation on how to extend this solution to multiple commands. Please check.

Comment: @ramiramilu - Thanks, the idea seems nice.

Answer (score 5):

I would have used `RemoteValidation`. I've found this simplest for scenarios like validations against database.

Decorate your property with Remote attribute -

```
[Remote("IsCityCodeValid","controller")]
public string CityCode { get; set; }
```

Now, "IsCityCodeValid" will be a action method, that will return JsonResult and take the property name  that you want to validate as parameter and "controller" is the name of controller in which your method will be placed. Make sure that the parameter name is same as property name.

Do your validations in the method, and in case it is valid return json true and false otherwise. Simple and quick!

```
    public JsonResult IsCityCodeValid(string CityCode)
    {
        //Do you DB validations here
        if (!cityRepository.IsValidCityCode(cityCode))
        {
            //Invalid
           return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {            
            //Valid
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

And you are done!!. MVC framework will take care of the rest.

And of course based on you requirement, you can use different overloads of remote attribute. You can also include other dependent properties, defining custome error message etc. You can pass even pass the model class as parameter to Json result action method
[MSDN Ref.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, never knew about this, i can use this in different context, not in the context of this question though.

Comment: @please read my question update Note # 2, no client side validation, if possible delete your answer

Comment: Thanks @PaRiMaLRaJ. I think I'll keep this answer for reference. Now that I am more clear about your problem, posted another solution. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use a [custom validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
public class UserAddress
{
    [CustomValidation(typeof(UserAddress), "ValidateCityCode")]
    public string CityCode {get;set;}
}
public static ValidationResult ValidateCityCode(string pNewName, ValidationContext pValidationContext)
{
    bool IsNotValid = true // should implement here the database validation logic
    if (IsNotValid)
        return new ValidationResult("CityCode not recognized", new List<string> { "CityCode" });
    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

Comment: Whilst you're on the right track, this isn't generic so the OP would have to build one of these for each one of his database lookup types, hence not the desired DRY approach :)

Comment: Based on this I think it's easy to build a generic solution, because you have access to the type of the object that need to be validated typeof(UserAddress)

Comment: @liviumamelluc i still cant see it DRY, and this has few additional complexity.

Comment: If the lookups are not varying alot like cities, you can add them in a cache component that will be initialize at application start and then validate them against that cache

Comment: If the lookups are not varying alot like cities, you can add them in a cache component that will be initialize at application start and then validate them against that cache

Comment: If the lookups are not varying alot like cities, you can add them in a cache component that will be initialize at application start and then validate them against that cache

Comment: @liviumamelluc cant cache -- the table has 10,000 + rows, and i have to apply similar logic many placed with huge table.

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to validate from database here are some techniques you can follow
1.using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations add reference to class

```
public int StudentID { get; set; }
[StringLength(50)]
public string LastName { get; set; }
[StringLength(50)]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
[StringLength(50)]
 public string MiddleName { get; set; }
```

here string lenght is defined i.e 50 and datetime can be nullable etc
[EF Database First with ASP.NET MVC: Enhancing Data Validation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation)

Comment: I think you understood my question another way.

Comment: please elaborate or Explain briefly

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in the past and it worked for me:

```
public interface IValidation
{
    void AddError(string key, string errorMessage);
    bool IsValid { get; }
}

public class MVCValidation : IValidation
{
    private ModelStateDictionary _modelStateDictionary;

    public MVCValidation(ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary)
    {
        _modelStateDictionary = modelStateDictionary;
    }
    public void AddError(string key, string errorMessage)
    {
        _modelStateDictionary.AddModelError(key, errorMessage);
    }
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return _modelStateDictionary.IsValid;
        }
    }
}
```

At your Business Layer level do something like this:

```
public class UserBLL
{
    private IValidation _validator;
    private CityRepository _cityRepository;
    public class UserBLL(IValidation validator, CityRepository cityRep)
    {
        _validator = validator;
        _cityRepository = cityRep;
    }
    //other stuff...
    public bool IsCityCodeValid(CityCode cityCode)
    {
        if (!cityRepository.IsValidCityCode(model.CityCode))
        {
            _validator.AddError("Error", "Message.");
        }
        return _validator.IsValid;
    }
}
```

And now at the controller level user your favorite IoC to register and instance of the `this.ModelState` into your `UserBLL`:

```
public class MyController
{
    private UserBLL _userBll;
    public MyController(UserBLL userBll)
    {
        _userBll = userBll;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Address(UserAddress model)
    {
        if(userBll.IsCityCodeValid(model.CityCode))
        {
            //do whatever
        }
        return View();//modelState already has errors in it so it will display in the view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd offer a very simple solution for server-side validation of fields that can only have values existing in database. First of all we'll need a validation attribute:

```
public class ExistAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    //we can inject another error message or use one from resources
    //aint doing it here to keep it simple
    private const string DefaultErrorMessage = "The value has invalid value";

    //use it for validation purpose
    private readonly ExistRepository _repository;

    private readonly string _tableName;
    private readonly string _field;

    /// <summary>
    /// constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tableName">Lookup table</param>
    /// <param name="field">Lookup field</param>
    public ExistAttribute(string tableName, string field) : this(tableName, field, DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ExistRepository>())
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// same thing
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tableName"></param>
    /// <param name="field"></param>
    /// <param name="repository">but we also inject validation repository here</param>
    public ExistAttribute(string tableName, string field, ExistRepository repository) : base(DefaultErrorMessage)
    {
        _tableName = tableName;
        _field = field;
        _repository = repository;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// checking for existing object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return _repository.Exists(_tableName, _field, value);
    }
}
```

Validation repository itself looks pretty simple as well:

```
public class ExistRepository : Repository
{
    public ExistRepository(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public bool Exists(string tableName, string fieldName, object value)
    {
        //just check if value exists
        var query = string.Format("SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM {0} l WHERE {1} = @value", tableName, fieldName);
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("@value", value);

        //i use dapper here, and "GetConnection" is inherited from base repository
        var result = GetConnection(c => c.ExecuteScalar<int>(query, parameters, commandType: CommandType.Text)) > 0;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here's base `Repository` class:

```
public class Repository
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public Repository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    protected T GetConnection<T>(Func<IDbConnection, T> getData)
    {
        var connectionString = _connectionString;
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            return getData(connection);
        }
    }
}
```

And now, what you need to do in model is mark your fields with `ExistAttribute`, specifying table name and field name for lookup:

```
public class UserAddress
{
    [Exist("dbo.Cities", "city_id")]
    public int CityCode { get; set; }

    [Exist("dbo.Countries", "country_id")]
    public int CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

Controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UserAddress(UserAddress model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) //you'll get false here if CityCode or ContryCode don't exist in Db
        {
            //do stuff
        }
        return View("UserAddress", model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt -

To start with, to identify what validation we need to perform on the property, we can have an enum as identifier.

```
public enum ValidationType
{
    City,
    //Add more for different validations
}
```

Next define our custom validation attribute something as follows, wherein the enum type is declared as attribute parameter -

```
public class ValidateLookupAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    //Use this to identify what validation needs to be performed
    public ValidationType ValidationType { get; private set; }
    public ValidateLookupAttribute(ValidationType validationType)
    {
        ValidationType = validationType;
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //Use the validation factory to get the validator associated
        //with the validator type
        ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = new ValidatorFactory();
        var Validator = validatorFactory.GetValidator(ValidationType);

        //Execute the validator
        bool isValid = Validator.Validate(value);

        //Validation is successful, return ValidationResult.Succes
        if (isValid)
            return ValidationResult.Success;

        else //Return validation error
            return new ValidationResult(Validator.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Going further if you need to add more validations, the attribute class need not to be changed.

And now simply decorate your property with this attribute

```
    [ValidateLookup(ValidationType.City)]
    public int CityId { get; set; }
```

Here are the other connecting parts of the solution-

Validator Interface. All validators will implement this interface. It has just a method to validate the object coming in and validator specific error message when validation fails.

```
public interface IValidator
{
    bool Validate(object value);

    string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

CityValidator Class (Of course you can improve this class with use of DI etc., its is just for ref purpose).

```
 public class CityValidator : IValidator
{
    public bool Validate(object value)
    {
        //Validate your city here
        var connection = ; // create connection
        var cityRepository = new CityRepository(connection);

        if (!cityRepository.IsValidCityCode((int)value))
        {
            // Added Model error
            this.ErrorMessage = "City already exists";
        }
        return true;
    }

    public ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Validator Factory, this is responsibel for providing correct validator associated with the validation type

```
public class ValidatorFactory
{
    private Dictionary<ValidationType, IValidator> validators = new Dictionary<ValidationType, IValidator>();

    public ValidatorFactory()
    {
        validators.Add(ValidationType.City, new CityValidator());
    }
    public IValidator GetValidator(ValidationType validationType)
    {
        return this.validators[validationType];
    }
}
```

Based on the design of your system and conventions, the actual implementation may vary slightly, but at high level it should address the problems nicely. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

- Hi.. I Think this is useful for Your Question.
- I use that method for
- calling single function in various Location. I will detailed explain
  below.

**In Model:**

```
public class UserAddress
{
    public string CityCode {get;set;}
}
```

**In Controller:**
First Create Single Function for Validate for single Connection

```
 public dynamic GetCity(string cityCode)
        {
           var connection = ; // create connection
           var cityRepository = new CityRepository(connection);

           if (!cityRepository.IsValidCityCode(model.CityCode))
           {
               // Added Model error
           }
           return(error);
        }
```

Function call from another controller like:

```
var error = controllername.GetCity(citycode);
```

**Other Method for Many connection**

```
 public dynamic GetCity(string cityCode,string connection)
            {

               var cityRepository = new CityRepository(connection);

               if (!cityRepository.IsValidCityCode(model.CityCode))
               {
                   // Added Model error
               }
               return(error);
            }
```

Function call from another controller like:

```
var error = controllername.GetCity(citycode,connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Lock has an elegant solution for doing this. By creating a custom validation attribute and then getting your external service from the validation context.

```
public class CustomValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var service = (IExternalService) validationContext
                         .GetService(typeof(IExternalService));

        // ... validation logic
    }
}
```

More detail here

https://andrewlock.net/injecting-services-into-validationattributes-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2022** asp.net core 6

With asp.net core 7 should be much more compact because of Generic Attributes. My idea is to make an abstract class for getting service through generics. And an interface for the validator. It is not tested yet.

**Attribute class:**

From ValidationContext is possible to get your service.

```
namespace Cart.Validation;

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class ProductExistsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var validator = (ProductValidator?)validationContext.GetService(typeof(ProductValidator));
        if (validator == null)
            throw new Exception("The validator is null. Did you register it?");

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((string?)value))
            return null;

        if (validator.IsProductExistsAsync((string)value).Result)
            return ValidationResult.Success;

        return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

**Entity:**

```
namespace Cart.Entity;

using Cart.Validation;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public partial class AddProductEshop
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product code missing")]
    [ProductEshopExists(ErrorMessage = "Product does not exist")]
    public string Code { get; set; } = null!;

    ...
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ProductValidator>();
```