# Validation attribute depending on object instance type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, validationattribute

I'm facing a conception problem. We could create and update our deals in two ways : using web forms (one to create deals, another one to edit them) and through an integration file (to allow mass creation & update).

```
public class CreateDealViewModel
{
    public int dealID { get; set; }

    [ValidateSalesman]
    public int SalesmanID { get; set; }
}

public class EditDealViewModel
{
    public int dealID { get; set; }

    [ValidateSalesman]
    public int SalesmanID { get; set; }

}

public class IntegrationLine
{
    public int DealID { get; set; }

    [ValidateSalesman]
    public int SalesmanID { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

I have a validation logic to implement : at deal creation, only active salesman are accepted ; in update, active salesman plus the previous salesman value (stored in DB) are accepted.

I wrote something like this :

```
public class ValidateSalesman : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var container = validationContext.ObjectInstance;
        if (container.GetType() == typeof(IntegrationLine))
        {
            if(((IntegrationLine)container).Status == "CREATION") 
            {
                //Validation logic here
            }
            else 
            {
                 //Validation logic here
            }
        }
        else if(container.GetType() == typeof(CreateDealViewModel)) 
        {
           //Validation logic here
        } 
        else if(container.GetType() == typeof(EditDealViewModel)) 
        {
           //Validation logic here
        } 
     }
 }
```

}

Is it a good approach (MVC compliant) or not ? Does the validation attribute has to know witch kind of model it applies on ?

Thanks in advance for any advice :)

Comment: You got to check this question which is running now on similar topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31110329/mvc-model-validation-from-database

Comment: Your approch is interesting (generic Validation Attribute and use of a repository for DB access). But i still have a doubt : in your exemple, you pass the value to check to the validator. In my case, I should send two parameters (the value, and creation/update status), so I still have to check my container type (CreateDealModelView, EditDealModelView or IntegrationFile). Is there anything wrong doing it ? Or should I send the whole container to the ValidatorCommand ?

Comment: In my approach, I am only sending Command Type. You should also do the same. Say create commands - CreateCommand, EditCommand etc., and then pass it to the validation attribute.

Comment: Ok, but how to know if I should call EditCommand or CreateCommand for the IntegrationFile ? (which could be with a creation or update status).

Comment: For example - `[Validate(IIntegrationLineCommand)] public int alesmanID { get; set; }`

Comment: I still have two problem with that :
- What to I do in my IntegrationLineCommand ? Because I need two parameters (status & value), and I your example you just send the value
- It's not really DRY in my case because some code will be duplicated between Edit/Create deal commands, and IntegrationFile command.