# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'StudentID'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I know there are many questions with this type of error, and I tried implementing those fixes to my issue, but nothing seems to work.

I believe the restriction in my Create() method in the EnrollmentController class from the ASP.Net Tutorials is giving this error message. I have a restriction where if a Student has been enrolled in a course before, he/she cannot enroll again. When I try to test the restriction, it gives me the ViewData error message.

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "EnrollmentID,CourseID,StudentID")]Enrollment enrollcourse)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var result = db.Enrollments.Count(u => u.StudentID == enrollcourse.StudentID && u.CourseID == enrollcourse.CourseID) == 0;
                    if (result)
                    {
                        TempData["success"] = "Course Enrolled";
                        db.Enrollments.Add(enrollcourse);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TempData["Already"] = "Student Has Already Enrolled This Course";
ViewBag.StudentId = new SelectList(db.People, "ID", "FullName", enrollcourse.StudentID);
                ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(db.Courses, "CourseId", "Title", enrollcourse.CourseID);
                        return View("Create");
                    }
                }

                return View(enrollcourse);
            }
```

The error message is telling me to fix this line of code in my *Views/Enrollment/Create.cshtml*

```
@Html.DropDownList("StudentID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I am new to .Net and C#, and I am trying my best to get through, but it is getting very confusing and complicated. What does it mean by "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable..." ?

Comment: Because you don't have a key of `StudentID`, you have a key of `StudentId`.  Use  `@Html.DropDownList("StudentId",...`

Comment: I tried changing it, but same type of error.

Comment: ModelState keys are not case-sensitive: StudentID == StudentId == StUdEnTiD. Doesn't matter.

Comment: Because `ModelState` is not valid and you have not populated `ViewBag.StudentId` before `return View(enrollcourse);`

Answer (score 1):

In the `else` block, you're returning the same View - without the ViewBag set.

Move those two ViewBag assigments to before the `if()` block.

Or rather:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "EnrollmentID,CourseID,StudentID")]Enrollment enrollcourse)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (!IsStudentEnrolled(enrollcourse))
        {
            db.Enrollments.Add(enrollcourse);
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["success"] = "Course Enrolled";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Already"] = "Student Has Already Enrolled This Course";
        }
    }

    ViewBag.StudentId = new SelectList(db.People, "ID", "FullName", enrollcourse.StudentID);
    ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(db.Courses, "CourseId", "Title", enrollcourse.CourseID);

    return View(enrollcourse);
}

private bool IsStudentEnrolled(Enrollment enrollcourse)
{
    return db.Enrollments.Count(u => u.StudentID == enrollcourse.StudentID && u.CourseID == enrollcourse.CourseID) == 0;        
}
```

Since you're returning to the Create view on both an invalid modelstate or an already enrolled course, you can just fall through to the last `return View(enrollcourse)`.

If you want to clear the view instead when the student is already enrolled to that course, then the `else` should reset the viewmodel:

```
else
{
    enrollcourse = null;
    ModelState.Clear();

    TempData["Already"] = "Student Has Already Enrolled This Course";
}
```

You could also [perform this validation in an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31110329/mvc-model-validation-from-database), if you need it at more places.

Comment: If I move the 2 ViewBag statements in the else loop, then the error message doesn't show, but it doesn't show the `TempData["Already"] = "Student Has Already Enrolled This Course";` message.

Comment: Then you're not rendering that string on your view.

Comment: I tried `return View("Already", enrollcourse);`, but it is giving me Server Error messages.

Comment: If you encounter an error, research it. That syntax is not for rendering TempData values on a view, it is instructing MVC to render a view named "Already", which doesn't exist, which is what the server error is telling you. You need `@Tempdata["Already"]` in your view file if you want to render that string.